# Why doesn't the JavaScript debugger pause at debugger statement?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I expect when I insert the JavaScript debugger statement into my JavaScript code that the program will pause at that point and the debugger will open showing the 'breakpoint'.

I'm not seeing this at all.

Here is my code.

```
<html>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  debugger;
  alert("Hello world!")
  </script>
  <body>
    <p>Hello world</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I run it - I go straight to the 'alert' popup on screen. What is the step I'm missing?

My question is: **Why doesn't the JavaScript debugger pause at debugger statement?**

(Just to clarify - I had the developer tools open - but at the 'console' tab, not the 'sources' tab.)

Comment: I think you need open developer tools first. Press F12

Comment: In a browser? Developer tools window is open? In IE the debugger is attached?

Comment: Some browsers requires the debugger to be opened beforehand.

Comment: If it doesn't work with the devtools open, try closing and reopening the devtools. I had to do this for some reason (presumably a bug).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to open the `Developer Tools` before the `debugger;` is executed.

**Open using <kbd>F12</kbd> key**
(read **[this](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)** to learn about more features)

---

#### See it in action:

*`Developer Tools` are not opened*

[image]

---

*`Developer Tools` are opened*

[image]

### http://jsfiddle.net/qkd5swv9/

Answer (score 17):

It looks like Chrome won't pause at `debugger;` statements when the JS code is minified.  I don't have source maps set up though.

Comment: THanks that clarified some doubts

Comment: I have question: in your minified test code the `debugger` statement was included? (may be minifier just remove it)

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Can you ask that at the top of the page? (hawkeye has the code, not me)

Comment: hawkeye give explicite code on his post without minification (and never mention about it) - but you mention about minification so I ask you - do you check this minification-case?

Comment: I don't think it has nothing to do with minimization itself but DevTools – Settings – Ignore List having a regex that *accidentally* hits the file you're trying to interrupt.

Answer (score 1):

The statement `debugger;` will behave as a JavaScript breakpoint given both of the following are true:

1. Chrome Developer Tools (DevTools) interface is already open.
2. The script with the statement `debugger` is not matched by any of the regular expressions in DevTools – Settings – Ignore List.